# Error in run sql file in postgres | No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, psql

### Problem

when in tried run sql file in psql shell...

give **"No such file or directory"** error!

```
$ ls
config.sql  config.yaml

$ sudo -i -u postgres psql

postgres=# \i config.sql

config.sql: No such file or directory
```

thanks for your reply!

### Quick solution:

-i => goes to user's home directory!

as result ./config.sql address is incorrect!

just use

```
$ psql -U <user_name>

postgres=# \i config.sql
```

Comment: You switched the current directory when you ran `sudo -i`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name problem solved! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man sudo` tells you:

> `-i`, `--login`
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
> resource files such as `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed
> to the shell for execution via the shell's `-c` option.

In particular, that will set your current working directory to the home directory of user `postgres`.

If you want to avoid that, don't use '-i'.

Comment: Where is the home directory of user `postgres`?

Comment: @SihatAfnan That depends on how you created the user. Try running `grep postgres /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f 6`.